# SQL Group by sum() and select first in denormalized data

Tags: sql

I have the following denormalised data:

```
╔════╦═══════╦══════════╦════════════╗
║ id ║ value ║ group_id ║ group_name ║
╠════╬═══════╬══════════╬════════════╣
║  0 ║    10 ║        0 ║ Group 0    ║
║  1 ║    10 ║        0 ║ Group 0    ║
║  2 ║    10 ║        0 ║ Group 0    ║
║  3 ║    10 ║        0 ║ Group 0    ║
║  4 ║    10 ║        1 ║ Group 1    ║
║  5 ║    10 ║        1 ║ Group 1    ║
║  6 ║    10 ║        1 ║ Group 1    ║
║  7 ║    10 ║        2 ║ Group 2    ║
║  8 ║    10 ║        2 ║ Group 2    ║
║  9 ║    10 ║        2 ║ Group 2    ║
╚════╩═══════╩══════════╩════════════╝
```

I am currently running a query that sums value by `group_id`:

```
select sum(value), group_id
from table
group by group_id
```

How do I extend this query to also include the `group_name` for each column? I need my result to look like:

```
╔═══════╦══════════╦════════════╗
║ value ║ group_id ║ group_name ║
╠═══════╬══════════╬════════════╣
║    40 ║        0 ║ Group 0    ║
║    30 ║        1 ║ Group 1    ║
║    30 ║        2 ║ Group 2    ║
╚═══════╩══════════╩════════════╝
```

Is the only way to do this to use `OVER`?

Comment: `select group_name,group_id,sum(value) from table group by group_name,group_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options.  One is to use an aggregation function:

```
select sum(value), group_id, max(group_name) as group_name
from table
group by group_id;
```

The second is to include the column unaggregated in the `select` and `group by`:

```
select sum(value), group_id, group_name
from table
group by group_id, group_name;
```

Comment: do mix, max, avg,.. aggregate functions work with string too? per SQL specification?

Answer (score 1):

Use `group by`!

```
select sum(value) as value, group_id, group_name
from mytable
group by group_id, group_name
```

In standard SQL, your original query is not a valid aggregation query to start with. All non-aggregated columns *must* appear in the `group by` clause (so you needed `group by` group_id`), although some databases (namely, MySQL) can be tweaked to allow otherwise.

Comment: ah - it's that simple?

Answer (score 1):

- Please specify db vendor.
- Your query `select sum(value), group_id from table` is invalid, I assume you run `select sum(value), group_id from table group by group_id`.
- Assuming you trust your denormalization and `group_name` always depends on `group_id`, you can just add `group_name` into `group by` and `select` clause: `select sum(value), group_id, group_name from table group by group_id, group_name`